# Encoding problem with Beatiful Soup + Python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I've been reading the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) for Beautiful Soup encoding try to get my html with special chars to parse. But the use cases there do not match mine.

The html `<p>Kimi Räikkönen</p>` is returned after being scraped as `Kimi RÃ¤ikkÃ¶nen` and my app cannot process this. The docs instruct how to convert content when the actual markup has unicode in it (which mine does not), i.e. `<p>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</p>`  to `<p>Sacré bleu!</p>`

Strangely when I enter `soup.original_encoding` I always get `None`, even with normal content.

I've tried all the examples from the docs and other questions like this here but none have worked so far. I am using Beatiful Soup as both scraper and parser.

I'd appreciate advice on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a Beautiful Soup issue but an issue with `requests`.

```
page = requests.get("https://www.formula1.com/en/drivers/kimi-raikkonen.html")
```

This was the first line I had inside my scraper and it was not returning the proper encoding. This solution might be considered hacky but I just added the following to fix the issue:

```
page.encoding = 'utf-8'
```